# CMake sub-directory include problems

Tags: cmake

I have a project structured as:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   └── temp.cpp
└── thirdparty
    ├── build
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── thirdparty.h
    └── src
        └── thirdparty.cpp
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `thirdparty` folder is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(thirdparty LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.0.1)
add_library(thirdparty SHARED "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/thirdparty.cpp")
target_include_directories(thirdparty PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/")
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file at the project root is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(temp LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.0.1)
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty"
                 "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/build"
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
#include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/include")
add_executable(temp "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/temp.cpp")
target_link_libraries(temp PRIVATE thirdparty)
```

The problem lies in trying to include a header file from the `thirdparty` library:

```
.../temp/src/temp.cpp:1:10: fatal error: thirdparty.h: No such file or directory
```

The `target_include_directories(thirdparty PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/")` directive works fine inside the `thirdparty` lib. However the header include path is not showing up with the  `add_subdirectory` command. Conversely the `libthirdparty.so` file generated links fine as long as I do `add_subdirectory` and `target_link_libraries(temp PRIVATE thirdparty)`.

The whole thing will work fine if I un-comment `#include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/include")` line in the root `CMakeLists.txt`, but I do not want to have a global include directive.

Is there a way to make the `thirdparty` headers visible by modifying the `CMakeLists.txt` in `thirdpary` only (along with `add_subdirectory` and `target_link_libraries` in root)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the include directories as PUBLIC or INTERFACE in the library built within `thirdparty`, and then link to this library *by using the name of the target* (and not the file name etc.) from other targets. This will leverage the target property system of cmake. The problem is that the `thirdparty` project you got may be obsolete (cmake 2.8 style or similar) and may thus not support this properly. It is often the case that "third party" project CMakeLists are subtly broken making them useless in multi-module projects and have to be altered or outright rewritten.

Under no circumstances will you need any explicit include directory directives etc. Just linking with the library target produced in a sub-directory is enough for cmake to bring in all the PUBLIC and INTERFACE dependencies as needed. That's the mechanism that makes cmake "sane". *You should not be using any variables such as FOOBAR_LIBRARY_INCLUDES etc. - that's ancient stuff and totally out of place in any modern cmake project, and by modern I mean anything made in the last 5+ years at the very least*.